# R programming - Adding extra column to existing matrix

Tags: r, statistics

I am a beginner to  R programming and am trying to add one extra column to a matrix having 50 columns. This new column would be the avg of first 10 values in that row.

```
randomMatrix <- generateMatrix(1,5000,100,50)
randomMatrix51 <- matrix(nrow=100, ncol=1)

for(ctr in 1:ncol(randomMatrix)){  
randomMatrix51.mat[1,ctr]  <- sum(randomMatrix [ctr, 1:10])/10
}
```

This gives the below error

```
Error in randomMatrix51.mat[1, ctr] <- sum(randomMatrix[ctr, 1:10])/10 :incorrect
number of subscripts on matrix
```

I tried this

```
cbind(randomMatrix,sum(randomMatrix [ctr, 1:10])/10)
```

But it only works for one row, if I use this cbind in the loop all the old values are over written.

How do I add the average of first 10 values in the new column. Is there a better way to do this other than looping over rows ?

Comment: I think you are getting your matrix indexing the wrong way round `x[i,j]` refers to rows `i` and columns `j`. Also, where does `generateMatrix` come from?

Comment: That solves a part of the problem. But is there a way to add an additional column to 'randomMatrix'.
If not will I have to 'cbind randomMatrix51' to 'randomMatrix'.

generateMatrix is function with params (lower lim, upper lim, no of rows, colmn). Its an in-built function in the standard library of R.

Comment: `transform(randomMatrix, new.col = new.data)` It would help a ton if you gave a much smaller example that can be completely cut and pasted into R with a better description of your desired results.

Answer (score 41):

Bam!

```
a <- matrix(1:5000, nrow=100)
a <- cbind(a,apply(a[,1:10],1,mean))
```

On big datasets it is however faster (and arguably simpler) to use:

```
cbind(a, rowMeans(a[,1:10]) )
```

Answer (score 4):

Methinks you are over thinking this.

```
a <- matrix(1:5000, nrow=100)
a <- transform(a,  first10ave = colMeans(a[1:10,]))
```